# #TestNg #JUnit #Maven #Selenium

Tags: maven, selenium, junit

Immediately after removing Junit from the pom.xml , an error is coming to my POM project.

a. I have removed Junit from pom.xml but it is still showing in the src folder.

The error sign should be removed

Comment: Please edit your question and add more details. With what you have provided there's hardly anything available for anyone to review your question and provide you with an answer.

Comment: The subject does not tell anybody what kind of problem you have ? furthermore your post does not contain the minimum of information ...the real error output? Your pom file? etc.